# How to group and handle priority extraction in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Now I would like to handle dataframe

`df`

```
A B
1 A0
1 A1
1 B0
2 B1
2 B2
3 B3
3 A2
3 A3
```

First, I would like to group by df.A

`sub1`

```
A B
1 A0
1 A1
1 B0
```

Second, I would like to extract first rows which contains letter `A`

```
A B
1 A0
```

If there is no `A`

`sub2`

```
A B
2 B1
2 B2
```

I would like to extract the first rows

```
A B
2 B1
```

So, I would like to get the result below

```
A B
1 A0
2 B1
3 A2
```

I would like to handle priority extraction,I tried grouping but Couldnt figure out. How to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby column *A* and for each group use `idxmax()` on `str.contains("A")`, then if there is A in column B, it will get the first index which contains letter *A*, otherwise it falls back to the first row as all values are *False*:

```
df.groupby("A", as_index=False).apply(lambda g: g.loc[g.B.str.contains("A").idxmax()])

#   A   B
#0  1   A0
#1  2   B1
#2  3   A2
```

---

In cases where you may have duplicated index, you can use `numpy.ndarray.argmax()` with `iloc` which accepts integer as position indexing:

```
df.groupby("A", as_index=False).apply(lambda g: g.iloc[g.B.str.contains("A").values.argmax()])

#   A   B
#0  1   A0
#1  2   B1
#2  3   A2
```